# Behavior of a Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff problem at infinity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, asymptotics, matrix-exponential

The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff problem is to obtain $\log(e^{X}e^{Y})$ where $X,Y$ are appropriate operators. The Dynkin series $$\log(e^{tX}e^{tY})=t(X+Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}[X,Y]+o(t^3)$$ gives an expansion in powers of a perturbation parameter $t$, with higher coefficients expressed in terms of successively more complicated commutators of $X,Y$. The parameter $t$ has been introduced to control the convergence of the series; so long as the operators $X,Y$ are bounded the Dynkin series has a finite radius of convergence (theorem 5 of Suzuki 1997). A more involved approach would be to replace $e^{t X}\to e^{s X}$; the appropriate Dynkin series would then presumably be in powers of $s,t$ and have finite radius of convergence in each variable.

Now suppose we instead consider the product $e^X e^{tY}$ for $t\gg 1$. My intuition had been that there would be an asymptotic series $$\log(e^{X} e^{tY})=tY+X+o(t^{-1}).$$ But this is clearly not the standard Dynkin series: powers of $t$ now only arise from the operator $Y$, and moreover $t=\infty$ will always fall outside the finite radius of convergence. Hence my question:

> Is there a known asymptotic series for $\log(e^Xe^{t Y})$ at large $t$?

References:
 - Suzuki, M. Commun.Math. Phys. (1977) 57: 193. doi:10.1007/BF01614161.

Comment: Full disclosure: I wasn't sure whether to put this here or on Math Stack Exchange; it is part of a research problem in mathematical physics, but if it seems out of place I can move it.

Comment: If $X,Y$ generate a nilpotent Lie algebra, then the Dynkin series terminates after finitely many terms and is an exact formula.  In particular, in this case $\log(e^X e^{tY})$ can certainly contain terms of order $t^2$ or greater in the large $t$ limit.

Comment: So the behavior at infinity will be sensitive to the algebraic structure. That's a bit frustrating but in retrospect unsurprising given how BCH simplifies when $[X,Y]$ is central in the subgroup. In my specific case, I actually do know that $[X,[X,Y]]$ is central; beyond that, though, I'd have to specialize further to obtain higher commutators. So I may not yet have enough info to get the asymptotic behavior..

Comment: But what can we say if we recall the majorization $\log\sigma(AB)\prec \log\sigma(A) + \log\sigma(B)$, which implies that $\log\sigma(e^Xe^{tY}) \prec \log\sigma(e^X)+|t|\log\sigma(e^Y)$? (here $\sigma$ denotes the singular value map)

Comment: I think the first question you should ask is, what is $\lim_{t\to \infty} e^{t Y}$?. The answer clearly depends strongly on $Y$. For example if all eigenvalues of $Y$ have negative real part the limit is zero. What can you say about $Y$? does it, for example, generate a contraction semigroup? (then answers are known)

Comment: In other words, not only the leading term may not be $t Y$, as @Carlo Beenakker 's answer shows, but it may actually be $O(1)$ (or not exist).

Comment: @lcv The $Y$ in my setting actually does satisfy that condition, so therefore $e^{tY}\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$ and my initial guess would indeed seem to have been quite mistaken. More precisely, the spectral decomposition should allow me $Y$ allow to write $e^{t Y}\sim e^{t\lambda_0} P_0$ where $\lambda_0<0$ is the largest real eigenvalue and $P_0$ is the projector to the corresponding subspace.

Comment: @Semiclassical This would work (for a semisimple eigenvalue). Unfortunately the other eigenvalues also contribute with terms which are linear in $t$ after taking the log (and so it doesn't..).  (note also that the leading term in $e^{tY}$ is given by the eigenvalue with largest *real part*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be helpful to consider an example that can be solved exactly; Using the [Special-case closed form of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02506) one finds that if the commutator $[X,Y]$ evaluates to
$$[X,Y]=uX +vY +cI$$
then the desired logarithm of the product of matrix exponentials equals
$$\log(e^X e^{tY})=tY+X+f(u,v,t)(uX +vY +cI)$$
$$f(u,v,t)=\frac{(ut-v)e^{ut+v}-ute^{ut}+ve^{v}}{uv(e^{ut}-e^{v})}$$
The large-$t$ limit can now be read off once the sign of $u$ is known:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(u,v,t)=\begin{cases}
-1/u&\text{if}\;u<0\\
(t/v)(e^v-1)&\text{if}\;u>0\\
(t/v)[v-1+v(e^v-1)^{-1}]&\text{if}\;u=0
\end{cases}$$
There are no terms greater than order $t$ in the large-$t$ limit for this class of commutators. *(I'm actually a bit puzzled how $t^2$ terms and higher might appear at all, an explicit example would help me a lot.)*

Comment: [@TerryTao](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/265854/behavior-of-a-baker-campbell-hausdorff-problem-at-infinity#comment656146_265854)'s comment explains how $t^2$ and higher terms can appear, no?  Namely, if, say, $X = E_{12} + E_{23}$ and $Y = E_{23} + E_{34}$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices, then, assuming my Mathematica scribbling hasn't gone awry, $e^X e^{t Y}$ is (exactly) the exponential of $X + t Y + \frac1 2[X, tY] + \frac1{12}([X, [X, tY]] + [[X, tY], tY])$.

Comment: As a physically relevant example, the displacement operator in coherent states satisfies the identity $$\hat{D}(\alpha)=e^{\alpha \hat{a}^\dagger-\alpha^\star \hat{a}}=e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{-\alpha \hat{a}^\dagger}e^{-\alpha^\star \hat{a}}$$ where $[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger]=1$ as typical for ladder operators. Specializing to real $\alpha$ then gives an example with terms of quadratic order.